# jQuery .each for Sub-elements

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to use jquery and it's each function to the get values in this type of structure:

```
     <div id="test">
       <p><input name="name1" value="Z1"></p>
       <p><input name="name2" value="Z2"></p>
       <p><input name="name3" value="Z3"></p>
       <p><input name="name4" value="Z4"></p>
      </div>
```

I've tried using

```
        $('#test').find('input').each(function () { }
        $('#test > p').children('input').each(function () { }
```

but the value I get using
alert($(this).value);
is always 'undefined'.  Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Either traversal method will work. But, if you're using jQuery, the syntax to determine a value is [`$(this).val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Otherwise, with vanilla JavaScript: [`this.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value). Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/rfw41vko/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use the selector `#test input` that will retrieve all the inputs on the `div`, which you'll be able to quickly access throught the `.each()` method, like so:

```
var values = [];
$('#test input').each(function (){
    values.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(values);
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmyqvkqe/) for more information.

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: that's a great idea for what I'm trying to do...thanks

Comment: @Allen if this answer solved your problem please mark it as the answer for future reference. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your two methods of retrieving the elements will work just fine. You're seeing `undefined` because of how you're accessing the input value: `.val()` not `.value`.

So:

```js
$('#test').find('input').each(function() {
  $(document.body).append($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <p><input name="name1" value="Z1"></p>
  <p><input name="name2" value="Z2"></p>
  <p><input name="name3" value="Z3"></p>
  <p><input name="name4" value="Z4"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go through each `<p>` tag because they have other siblings, and then in the each function find the input and get the value.

This will work:

```
$('#test > p').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).find('input').val();
});
```

Comment: His method will also work. When you use `.find()` on a collection, it searches all the members and combines the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $('#test input').each(function(i,v){
            console.log($(this).val());
       });
```

Explanation: We have a selector of `'#test input'` which means that we are searching for all `input`s directly or transitively inside `#test`. So far, so good. However, we need their `value`s, therefore, inside the function we log the result of `$(this).val()` which will output the values to the console.

Answer (score 0):

first one is working mate. I am not sure what's your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/tsj0w29x/ `$('#test').find('input').each(function () {
alert($(this).value);
}`

Comment: Your fiddle has a syntax error, it's missing the closing `)`.